# How to handle key events in select2 dropdown of jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

For Select2 component in jquery where minimumResultsForSearch is Infinity, When the results box is open and When I click on any alphabet on keyboard, for example 'k', results should scroll automatically and should show the list item that starts with that particular alphabet which is 'k'.

FYI, this is default behavior in HTML for a select component, but in select2 plugin this feature has been disabled.

Now I need to achieve this for my client. What could be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried yourself so far to achive this?`

Comment: Nothing that i think of.